# Symfony error: Attribute "Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route" cannot target function (allowed targets: class, method)

Tags: php, symfony

After upgrading from Symfony 6.1 to 6.2, I'm getting this error:

> Attribute "Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route" cannot target function (allowed targets: class, method)

...on this controller:

```php
final class HomepageController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function __invoke(): Response
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer

Doing one of the following will fix it:

- Update PHP to >= 8.1.10
- Move the `Route` attribute from `__invoke()` upwards to `class`

### Long Answer

Symfony's `Route` attribute is allowed on classes and methods, see [Route](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Annotation/Route.php):

```php
#[\Attribute(\Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE | \Attribute::TARGET_CLASS | \Attribute::TARGET_METHOD)]
```

In Symfony 6.2 the way how attributes are read, has changed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/46001

Unfortunately, there was a bug introduced in PHP 8.1.6, so that the magic method `__invoke()` isn't covered by `\Attribute::TARGET_METHOD` anymore.

This was fixed in PHP 8.1.10: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/9173